# Firebase iOS SDK `setValue` completion inconsistantly called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using:

`func setValue(value: AnyObject?, withCompletionBlock block: (NSError?, FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void)`

as part of the Firebase iOS sdk, the completion block will inconsistently get called when persistence is enabled.

I realize that the the completion should not get called if there is no network connection and that it will update locally and only call the completion when it sends the data up to the server, however I can watch the record being created in the firebase console and my completion block being called is still not consistent.

If I turn off `persistanceEnabled` the call will function as expected.

Here is my method.  ref is a `FIRDatabaseReference` and `json` is the objects representation as json

```
func lightSave(completion: FBModelUpdateCompletion? = nil) {
    print("Light Saving \(ref)")
    ref.setValue(json, withCompletionBlock: { (error, result) in
        print("finished saving")
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        completion?(error: error, object: self)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"I realize that the the completion should not get called if there is no network connection"

That's not true -- the completion block will *also* get called when there's no network connection and you have `persistenceEnabled` turned on.

The rationale here is that you should be letting the Firebase database be your one true source of data in your app, and if you have to start worrying about whether or not you're connected and relying on database updates if you are connected or managing it yourself manually if you're not, things will get messy.

So if you're not connected to the database but have persistenceEnabled turned on, Firebase will treat the "I'm updating my data to the local cache to be saved later" call just as if the online database itself got updated, so you can continue to treat your Firebase reference as an accurate source of data.